# File.Exists() always returns false

Tags: c#

This is my code (.Net 4):

```
 string dName = textBox1.Text + ".db";
 string fExist = @"C:\word_app\" + dName;
 if (!File.Exists(fExist))
 {
   MessageBox.Show("file doesnt exist");
 }
```

Even if I have the file in that location , this messagebox will appear.[image]

Comment: So? What is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the file doesn't exist?..

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there is a file at "C:\word_app\somefile.db"

Comment: Maybe check if the file is **really** there? `MessageBox.Show("file doesnt exist" + fExist);`

Comment: even if i have the file in that location , this messagebox will apear

Comment: i check that folder and that file really exists

Comment: Maybe a permission issue.  Your app doesn't have access to that file?

Comment: Try this: `string dName = textBox1.Text.Trim() + ".db";`

Comment: it can create files in that folder

Comment: Try showing fExist in a messagebox to see where it is actually looking

Comment: Change message box message to `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("file '{0}' doesnt exist", fExist));` and verify file name

Comment: Please supply an image of the file in that location with the visible path (top of explorer) along with a screenshot of the textbox.

Comment: why don't you log some stuff, like the variable fExist

Comment: @RickS, the program would throw an exception.

Comment: put a break point at  if (!File.Exists(fExist)) line and check what exactly is the fExist string?

Comment: the path is true , i have checked it via messagebox. how i can check the permissions for this app ?

Comment: Right now you have given us the code equivalence of  "5 + x = 11 and I know that x is 6. Why does it say my equation isn't correct?". We need more information: provide proof of your claims.

Comment: try running your app as admin

Comment: @TMcKeown: no, `File.Exists` would return `false` if it's a permission issue. `If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @T McKeown - read up on the documentation before you post.   If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.

Comment: hmmm... well damn.  I guess I assumed there would be an exception thrown.

Comment: and how can I give permissions to this app for those files that it creates ?

Comment: Where is your code running?  Is it a web app, console app, etc...

Comment: @user3306372 Look up the file in Windows Explorer, right-click it, open its properties, go to Security tab, and add your user to the list of users who can access the file.

Comment: The path in your screenshot and the path in your code do not match

Comment: words_app not word_app?

Comment: Theres an S you are not putting in your code

Comment: replace "word_app" with "words_app"

Comment: oh thanks Golden Dragon :)

Comment: +1 simply out of sympathy - we have all missed that semi colon or spelling mistake at some point

Comment: thanks to all of you , guys , for spending time to resolve it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have just to correct your path (its words not word)

```
string dName = textBox1.Text + ".db";
string fExist = @"C:\words_app\" + dName;
if (!File.Exists(fExist))
{
  MessageBox.Show("file doesnt exist");
}
```